# Reference a counter without incrementing

Tags: cross-referencing, counters

I'm trying to reference a counter without increment it.  I have

```
\newcounter{procstep}
\newcommand{\refproc}[1]{\addtocounter{procstep}{-1}\refstepcounter{procstep}\label{#1}}
```

Is this the correct way to do this?  I was wondering if there was a simpler way? I was sort of expecting a `\refcounter` macro.

Comment: I think you want `\theprocstep`

Comment: Also see if this helps: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Counters#Counter_access

Comment: @Mark: `\theprocstep` itself is not frozen to provide a label as a `state` when being referred to it. You have to write the current value to the `.aux`

Comment: It would also be quite useful to know **why** this should be useful?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer - I have a table that increments the first column by 10 on every new row.  This keeps the number correct if I insert new rows arbitarily to the table.  I would like to be able to reference the row number (procstep) from other rows - i.e. repeat rows 20-40 where 20-40 are labels to other rows that may change

Comment: @RossW: Labels hidding inside of table cells might get lost

Answer (score 4):

Similar to John Kormylo's answer, but a little bit shorter. (See the extended version at the end of this post)

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{procstep}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\providecommand{\phantomsection}{}



\makeatletter
\newcommand{\statlabel}[1]{%
  \phantomsection
  \protected@edef\@currentlabel{\theprocstep}%
  \protected@edef\@currentlabelname{procstep}%
  \label{#1}%
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

See \ref{first}

\blindtext[10]
\setcounter{procstep}{100} \fbox{Here is the label\statlabel{first}}



\end{document}
```

**Extended version for any counter**

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{procstep}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\providecommand{\phantomsection}{}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\statlabel}{omm}{%
  \phantomsection%
  \protected@edef\@currentlabel{\csname the#2\endcsname}%
  \IfValueT{#1}{%
    \protected@edef\@currentlabelname{#1}%
  }%
  \label{#3}%
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

See \ref{first} or \nameref{first} or \ref{seclabel} and \nameref{seclabel} or \autoref{seclabel} 

\blindtext[10]

\setcounter{section}{17}% Just for fun
\statlabel[Some foo text]{section}{seclabel}


\setcounter{procstep}{100}\fbox{Here is the label\statlabel[Static Label to procstep]{procstep}{first}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't exactly call this simpler, unless you throw out the hyperref option.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcounter{procstep}

\makeatletter
\@ifpackageloaded{hyperref}%
    {\newcommand{\refproc}[1]{\protected@edef\@currentlabelname{procstep}%
    \Hy@MakeCurrentHrefAuto{procstep}%
    \Hy@raisedlink{\hyper@anchorstart{\@currentHref}\hyper@anchorend}%
    \protected@write\@auxout{}{\string\newlabel{#1}{{\theprocstep}{\thepage}%
      {\@currentlabelname}{\@currentHref}{}}}}}%
  {\newcommand{\refproc}[1]{\protected@write\@auxout{}{\string\newlabel{#1}{{\theprocstep}{\thepage}}}}}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\ref{test}
\setcounter{procstep}{23}
\refproc{test}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think, you could let do `hyperref` most of the things you're using `\phantomsection` and provide `\@currentlabelname` and `\currentlabel` only

Comment: Thanks John - Definitely not simpler... :) The version I came up with works well - I was just surprised that there wasn't a (obvious) way of getting the reference without actual performing an operation on the counter

Comment: OTOH, this is precisely what \refstepcounter and \label do, minus incrementing the counter.